# Which backup software for Windows Server to Linux server backups?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, ssh, rsync

I need to use a backup software that can backup windows server to a Linux server out side the network (the cloud)!

So far I came through the following:

Handy Backup Professional 6.7 Backup4all Professional 4.4 BatchSync Secure 3.0

What I need is

- a possibility to backup to SSH(SFTP) or better RSYNC over SSH
- full,differential, incremental
- possibility to limit the backup snapshots history by size or numbers? like the total backup (snapshots) will not go over some ... GB or/and not more than 4 snapshots

here is another thing what I think as an "ideal" backup system is to have yearly (yearly archive), monthly (last 12 moths), weekly (last 2 or 3 weeks), daily (last 7 days)

I know it is all depend on the data type and the storage that I have.

So is there any one who can advice me for for a good backup program (one of the above or any other)? good backup strategy?

*Note: the good guys at superuser.com told me to ask here :-)

Thanks!*

Comment: When you say cloud - are any of your servers virtualised or physical.  If virtualised there are a bunch of other options not available for physical.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said SSH or rsync over SSH. If you have any choice at all when it comes to protocol (i.e. open ports), bacula might be an option for you. It definitely offers the flexibility you need, and it has a Windows client (which can even back up Exchange databases).

Bacula normally runs on ports 9101, 9102 and 9103, but it can be configured to run on any port you need (although I have never tried that).

Answer (score 1):

If Bacula looks too heavy for you, take a look at [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) - it's a cracking bit of Open Source backup software. We use it to backup around 30 Windows servers via ADSL VPNs to 5 distributed backup servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend avoiding anything other than full backups - although staging to a mirror using rsync can save a lot of bandwidth (note you still need snapshots to resolve issues with files accidentally deleted or corrupted).

There are rsync implementations for MS Windows ([this link](http://rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) also points to another backup solution). And ssh implementations. But you might also want to have a look at [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/)

Answer (score 0):

so the software that I found was [BackupAssist](http://www.backupassist.com/index.html)

hope you will find it useful!

cheers